# Multiple conditional sums in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to return the total of requests by type based on their status:

- If there is **no status set**, the request should be added to `requested`
- If the status is **ordered**, the request should be added to `ordered`
- If the status is **arrived**, the request should be added to `arrived`

  ```
  caseRequest.aggregate([{
    $group: {
      _id: "$product",
      suggested: {
        $sum: {
            $cond: [{
              $ifNull: ["$status", true]
            },
            1, 0
        ]}
      },
      ordered: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{
                $eq: ["$status", "ordered"]
            },
            1, 0
          ]
        }
      },
      arrived: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{
               $eq: ["$status", "arrived"]
            },
            1, 0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

But for some reason it doesn't find any request status **ordered** or **arrived**. If in the database I have **48 requests**, 45 of them without status, 2 with ordered and 1 with arrived, it returns:

```
[
    {
        _id: "xxx",
        suggested: 48,
        ordered: 0,
        arrived: 0,
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach,

> Return the total number of requests by type based on their status

Now the simplest way to get the count of different status is to use aggregate pipeline with $group on the status field

```
db.stackoverflow.aggregate([{ $group: {_id: "$status", count: {$sum:1}} }])
```

We will be getting a result similar to this

```
{ "_id" : "", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "arrived", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "ordered", "count" : 4 }
```

The schema which is used to retrieve these records is very simple so that it will be easier to understand. The schema will have a parameter on the top level of the document and the value of status can be "ordered", "arrived" or empty

**Schema**

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("5798c348d345404e7f9e0ced"), "status" : "ordered" }`

The collection is populated with 9 records, with status as ordered, arrived and empty

```
db.stackoverflow.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5798c348d345404e7f9e0ced"), "status" : "ordered" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5798c349d345404e7f9e0cee"), "status" : "ordered" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5798c34ad345404e7f9e0cef"), "status" : "ordered" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5798c356d345404e7f9e0cf0"), "status" : "arrived" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5798c357d345404e7f9e0cf1"), "status" : "arrived" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5798c358d345404e7f9e0cf2"), "status" : "arrived" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5798c35ad345404e7f9e0cf3"), "status" : "ordered" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5798c361d345404e7f9e0cf4"), "status" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5798c362d345404e7f9e0cf5"), "status" : "" }

db.stackoverflow.count()
9
```

Hope it Helps!!